# How can I check if a file exists in python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to make a python script to make entries in an excel file that will have daily entries.
I want to check if a file exists then open it.
if the file does not exist then I want to make a new file.

if have used os path exists to see if the file is present

```
     workbook_status = os.path.exists("/log/"+workbookname+".xlxs")
     if  workbook_status = "True":
     # i want to open the file
     Else:
     #i want to create a new file
```

Comment: So what's missing from your current code is writing to an existing or new file? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: yes,  writing to existing file. i want to know if the load_workbook() will overwrite the existing file or it will just open it and then i can append to the existing file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you just need that

```
try:
    f = open('myfile.xlxs')
    f.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist')
```

If you want to check with if-else than go for this:

```
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path("/path/to/file")
if my_file.is_file():
    # file exists
```

OR

```
if os.path.isfile("/{file}.{ext}".format(file=workbookname, ext=xlxs)):
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
import os.path

PATH='./file.txt'

if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    print "File exists and is readable/there"
else:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use following statement:

```
if os.path.isfile("/{file}.{ext}".format(file=workbookname, ext=xlxs)):
    #  Open file
```